# Scale Azure web app with Azure Management Libraries for .NET

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to scale Web App and change pricing tier using .NET API?

If not, is it possible with REST API or Power Shell?

Please note, that I am interesting in scaling of web apps, not cloud services.

P. S.
I found a solution: it is possible to scale web app using Azure SDK by running `azure site scale` command. More information here: http://microsoftazurewebsitescheatsheet.info/#scale-configuration

Comment: This question is about web apps, question asked by pksorensen is about cloud services. It is not the same. Difference is described here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRokvazNZKXonjHpfsX97esvXKW%2BlMI%2F0ER3fOvrPUfGjI4CS8ZgI%2BSLDwEYGJlv6SgFS7XCMadx37gOUxM%3D

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520370/scale-azure-webapp-using-net-sdk