# Scale Azure WebApp using .NET SDK

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sdk-.net

Description of the [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites/) NuGet package says that it

"*Provides management capabilities for Microsoft Azure Web Sites. Deploy, configure, debug, and **scale** your websites*"

What class and methods should I use to perform a scaling operation?

My previous question on this topic was marked as duplicated, but I don't agree, here is an explanation:
[Scale Azure web app with Azure Management Libraries for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729496/scale-azure-web-app-with-azure-management-libraries-for-net#comments-29729496)

Comment: Good question. I'll search how to do that using SDK. For now, did you try Scale Application Block? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680892(v=pandp.50).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will definitely try it. My initial idea is to make my own scaling algorithm and compare it with standard WASABI and AzureWatch implementations

Comment: I dont believe WASABi will work for WebApps and it being obsoleted anyway.  FYI: AzureWatch is replaced by CloudMonix at http://cloudmonix.com  For your needs, try changing the NumberOfWorkers in the WebApp configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this PSEUDO code.  You'll need to transform config from Response to Update model.

```
            var config = client.WebSites.GetConfiguration(webspace, website);
            config.NumberOfWorkers = targetScaleSize;
            var result = client.WebSites.UpdateConfiguration(webspace, website, config);
```

Comment: Thanks, you shown me right direction, I used client.WebHostingPlans.Update which allows to update worker size in addition to number of workers